# сколько раз подряд встречается символ в массиве

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Дан массив символов,надо напечатать символ и сколько раз подряд он встретился.

> Например: aaaaaaabbbbbbcccccdaaa. a 7 b 6 c 5 d 1 a 3

Вот моя программа, но она зацикливается.

```
type mas=array[1..100] of char;
var i,j,n,k:integer;
x:mas;
begin
i:=0;
repeat
i:=i+1;
read(x[i]);
until x[i]='.';
n:=1;
k:=1;
while n<i do begin
  write(x[n],' ');
 if x[n] = x[Succ(n)] then
 while x[n] = x[Succ(n)] do begin
  n:=n+1;
  inc(k);
  end;
  writeln(k);
    end;
 end.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Юля, здесь не нужны два `while`, они Вас запутывают. Напишите один цикл `for`. Храните в переменных предыдущий символ и число повторений. Сравнивайте текущий символ с предыдущим. Если они одинаковые - увеличивайте число повторений. Если они разные - выводите предыдущий символ и накопленое число повторений, предыдущий символ меняйте на текущий, а число повторений устанавливайте равным 1.

Answer (score 0):

Это ж PascalABC.Net, тут есть словари и всякие удобные штучки. Зачем так мучиться.

```
// PascalABC.Net 3.7.1

uses System.Collections.Generic;

begin
    var s := ReadString('Введите строку символов');
    var CountChars := new Dictionary<char, integer>(); 
    
    for var i := 1 to Length(s) do
    begin
        if (i = 1) or (s[i - 1] <> s[i]) then begin
            if CountChars.ContainsKey(s[i]) then 
                CountChars[s[i]] := 0
            else CountChars.Add(s[i], 0);
        end;
        CountChars[s[i]] += 1;
    end;
    
    foreach kv: KeyValuePair<char, integer> in CountChars do
        WritelnFormat('{0} - {1}', kv.Key, kv.Value);
end.
```

А это вариант для частотного анализа, без условия подряд

```
// PascalABC.Net 3.7.1

uses System.Collections.Generic;

begin
    var s := ReadString('Введите строку символов');
    var CountChars := new Dictionary<char, integer>(); 
    
    foreach c: char in s do
        if CountChars.ContainsKey(c) then
            CountChars[c] += 1
        else CountChars.Add(c, 1);
    
    foreach kv: KeyValuePair<char, integer> in CountChars do
        WritelnFormat('{0} - {1}', kv.Key, kv.Value);
end.
```

Comment: Вы решаете не ту задачу, что была поставлена.

Comment: и правда, не учла условие "подряд", спасибо

Comment: И словарь получается не нужен Оптимальный способ уже описан в ответе Igor